# How to say "mix speech styles"?

Tags: translation

I have been trying to find the right way to translate "mixing speech styles". So far my internet searches have not yielded any results.

An example to show what I want to communicate: "I often tend to mix informal and formal speech".

If anybody can help me out, I will be very grateful! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

じょうたい【常体】 Plain. Informal.
けいたい【敬体】 Polite. Formal.
ぶんたい【文体】 style

文体を混ぜる。
常体と敬体を混ぜる。